# Why is my first set of numbers on the closed parenthesis stuck on 21?

Tags: arrays, visual-studio-2010, numbers, vb.net-2010, skip

I want the output to have the numbers on the first set to go from 0-20 and the second set to 0-100 but not 0,1,2,3,4,5 but 0,5,10 basically skipping each 5. Here's a screenshot of my code and output.

Code:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code. Post the code in the post itself, properly formatted as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple options for you...

Option 1:

```
For a As Integer = 0 To 20
    Dim b As Integer = a * 5
    Console.WriteLine("index number:({0}) = {1}", a, b)
Next
```

Option 2:

```
Dim b As Integer = 0
For a As Integer = 0 To 20
    Console.WriteLine("index number:({0}) = {1}", a, b)
    b = b + 5
Next
```

Option 3:

```
Dim a As Integer = 0
Dim b As Integer = 0
While a <= 20
    Console.WriteLine("index number:({0}) = {1}", a, b)
    a = a + 1
    b = b + 5
End While
```

In C#, you could do:

```
for(int a=0,b=0; a<=20; a++,b+=5) {
  Console.WriteLine("index number:({0}) = {1}", a, b);
}
```